# How to verify a signature in openSSL given just the public modulus and exponent in unsigned char arrays

Tags: openssl, rsa, modulus, exponent

I have read many of the related articles and have tried out the coding examples but my call to RSA_verify still fails.  Here are my details:

I'm writting an application that executes in multiple stages.  A public key (2048 bits) is read in from a .pub file in the first stage but only the modulus and exponent in unsigned char arrays are passed onto subsequent stages (those subsequent stages do not know what the original key file was).

In one of the stages I have to verify a hash against a signature that was signed by the private key (by a seperate application) but all that I have to go with are the unsigned char arrays for the mod and exp.  I've tried creating the RSA structure and then passing that into the RSA_verfiy function (along with the signature) but I get the following error:

```
5040:error:0306E06C:bignum routines:BN_mod_inverse:no inverse:.\crypto\bn\bn_gcd.c:492:
```

Here's a facimile of my code:

```
bool RSAVerifySig( uchar *hash, uint hashSize,
                   uchar *sig, uint sigSize,
                   uchar *mod, uchar *exp )
{
    RSA     *rsa = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM  *n = BN_new();
    BIGNUM  *e = BN_new();

    BN_bin2bn( mod, 256, n );
    BN_copy( rsa->n, n );
    BN_bin2bn( exp, 4, e );
    BN_copy( rsa->e, e );
    rsa->iqmp = NULL;
    rsa->d = NULL;
    rsa->p = NULL;
    rsa->q = NULL;
    ret = RSA_verify( EVP_sha256()->type, hash, hashSize, sig, sigSize, rsa );
    if( 0 != ERR_peek_error() )
    {
            SSL_load_error_strings();
            ERR_print_errors_fp( stdout );
            return( false );
    }
    return( ret == 1 );
}
```

I've been banging my head on this for a few days now.  If anyone can help it would be well appreciated.

Comment: Can you backtrace your code? What's the call sequence before you encounter this error?

Comment: The routine that calls this routine reads in a binary file that contains the binary data (blob) to be verified.  The format of the blob is "data to be signed (DTBS)" || modulus || exponent || signature.The DTBS is generated in one stage with the modulus and exponent appended to it.  This partial blob is then sent to a secure facility where the signature is generated and appended to the partial blob.  This blob is then returned back (not necessarily to the originating facility for integration but the signature needs to be verified first.